# R Reshape Wide to Long with Stubs

Tags: r, data.table

```
HAVE = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,2),
                  CLASS = c(100,200),
                  T1CHE=c(95,NA),
                  T2CHE=c(13,66),
                  T3CHE=c(99,1),
                  T1CHES=c(81,NA),
                  T2CHES=c(43,59),
                  T3CHES=c(3,25),
                  P11MATH=c(56,88),
                  P12MATH=c(33,40),
                  P5MATHS=c(100,31),
                  P6MATHS=c(88,36),
                  T2ENG=c(37,63),
                  T3ENG=c(46,38),
                  T4ENG=c(14,74))


WANT = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                  CLASS = c(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200),
                          TIME=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12),
                          CHE=c(95,13,99,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,66,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                          CHES=c(81,43,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,59,25,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                          MATH=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,56,33,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,88,40),
                          MATHS=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,100,88,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,31,36,NA,NA),
                          ENG=c(NA,37,46,14,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,63,38,74,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

I have a bunch of variables in 'HAVE' measure repeatedly and with STUBS. I wish to convert from wide 'HAVE' into long 'WANT' without have to specify all of the STUBS but some of them are similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `pivot_longer`, `separate_wider_regex` and `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package like so:

Note: Your example contained a duplicated column name. As a result we end up with `MATH` and `MATH.1`.

```r
library(tidyr)

HAVE |>
  pivot_longer(-c(STUDENT, CLASS)) |>
  separate_wider_regex(
    name,
    patterns = c("P|T", TIME = "\\d+", variable = ".*")
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "variable",
    values_from = "value"
  )
#> # A tibble: 16 × 9
#>    STUDENT CLASS TIME    CHE  CHES  MATH MATH.1 MATHS   ENG
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1       1   100 1        95    81    NA     NA    NA    NA
#>  2       1   100 2        13    43    NA     NA    NA    37
#>  3       1   100 3        99     3    NA     NA    NA    46
#>  4       1   100 11       NA    NA    56     NA    NA    NA
#>  5       1   100 12       NA    NA    33     70    NA    NA
#>  6       1   100 5        NA    NA    NA     NA   100    NA
#>  7       1   100 6        NA    NA    NA     NA    88    NA
#>  8       1   100 4        NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    14
#>  9       2   200 1        NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA
#> 10       2   200 2        66    59    NA     NA    NA    63
#> 11       2   200 3         1    25    NA     NA    NA    38
#> 12       2   200 11       NA    NA    88     NA    NA    NA
#> 13       2   200 12       NA    NA    40     89    NA    NA
#> 14       2   200 5        NA    NA    NA     NA    31    NA
#> 15       2   200 6        NA    NA    NA     NA    36    NA
#> 16       2   200 4        NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    74
```

Comment: thank you!! why does it do 'CHE CHES' but 'MATH MATH.1 MATHS' ?

Comment: In your original example data there were two columns named `P12MATH`. In general we can't and won't have two columns with the same name in a df. As `data.frame()` checks the names by default one of those columns was automatically renamed to `P12MATH.1`. That's why in my answer we end up with columns `MATH` and `MATH.1`.

Comment: thank you so so much. i have question, i run on this on my school district data and get this error that i try to debug all day:

Error in `separate_wider_regex()`:
! Expected each value of `name` to match the pattern, the whole pattern, and nothing but the pattern.
! 64881180 values have problems.
ℹ Use `too_few = "debug"` to diagnose the problem.
ℹ Use `too_few = "start"` to silence this message.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Hm. The issue is most likely that the patterns do not match the column names, i.e. `patterns = c("P|T", TIME = "\\d+", variable = ".*")` means that each (!!) column starts with a P or T followed by one or more digits and more symbols of any kind. The first letter gets dropped, the matched digits are assigned to TIME and other symbols to variable. If your names don't follow this pattern you will get an error.

Comment: First check your column names. If some don't follow the pattern you have to adapt it, e.g. if the column names could start with letters or symbols different from P or T you could use the more general `c("^.*?", ...)` to match any number of symbols in front of the digits.

Comment: I double check and seems ok but still error..the format is 'P or T' & 1- or 2-digit number & LETTERS or NUMBERS or COMBINATION of the two so would it be 

patterns=c("^.*?", TIME = "\\d+", variables = ".*")

Comment: Hm. What I do in such cases. Use `too_few="debug"` as suggested in the error message, i.e. run `pivot_longer(...) |> separate_wider_regex(..., too_few = "debug")`. Instead of returning an error additional columns are added to the dataframe from which help to debug the issue, e.g. if you use `name` as I did in my code there will be a `name_ok` column with TRUE and FALSE for the names where the pattern matched or failed. Then you can filter for the FALSE values to find the non-matching names.